# How do I get my PC's interested in the Hoard of the Dragon Queen?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, optimization, campaign-development

I have Hoard of the Dragon Queen and I'm concerned my new PC's are going to be bored. What do you do as a GM to keep players interested?

1. Real players
2. Player charcters
   (Unfortunately we just rolled out characters and don't have sheets to explain who/how each character came about).

Opinions acceptable. However I would prefer sourced material from the book.

Comment: User81620, you appear to have accidentally made this second account. You should probably [merge them using these instructions](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to keep all you Q&As under one account.

Answer (score 3):

**You are not forced to play it as it is written**

If a published adventure turns out to be boring, and to me it happened a lot of times, you can always edit it as you want without telling your PCs.
Keep in mind that if their characters are interested in the story even their players will be.

**So how can you edit a story to make it more interesting?**

- Don't overdo, write down only what you need for the next session, so that you won't concentrate on minor or futile things
- Try to study their characters and know what they are good at and what they are not. Make interesting challenges, suited for them.
- Create an immersive ambient: no phones, describe in details and maybe add some music but not too distractive
- Play with their emotions: will it be a disturbing session with worms and insects, will it be a scary session with armies of skeletons and ghouls or an adventurous one with high mountains to climb to reach a goal in time?
- Keep them focused, if you see someone absent-minded don't lecture him but instead ask him what will his character do.
- Know when to stop talking and let them discuss together what to do in that situation and if they don't you didn't do a good job

**No matter what campaign will be yours, FUN is always the keyword**

Comment: I'm currently DMing it and my PCs are followers of Tiamat that believe summoning her is blasphemous. Just an example of possible modifications for groups not interested in the default hook, which is not very good.